# CoreData JSON Mapping

Tags: ios, json, core-data, mapping

In my api i have a JSON output like this;

```
{
"restaurants": [{
    "Restaurant": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "...",
        "slug": "...",
        "phone": "2161234567",
        "address": "...",
        "city_id": "34",
        "county_id": "426",
        "discount_type_id": null,
        "discount": "",
        "people_limit": "2",
        "reservations_required": false,
        "lat": "41.015608",
        "lon": "28.934834",
        "about": "...",
        "logo": "...",
        "logo_dir": "3",
        "photo_1": "...",
        "photo_2": null,
        "photo_3": null,
        "photo_dir": "3",
        "created": "2012-11-30 16:30:21",
        "modified": "2012-11-30 20:43:50",
        "deleted": true
    },
    "AvailabilityRestriction": [{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "...",
        "AvailabilityRestrictionRestaurant": {
            "id": "28",
            "restaurant_id": "3",
            "availability_restriction_id": "1"
        }
    }],
    "CuisineTag": [{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "...",
        "CuisineTagRestaurant": {
            "id": "47",
            "restaurant_id": "3",
            "cuisine_tag_id": "3"
        }
    }]
},

...
}
```

Restaurant has many cuisine_tags and availability restrictions. Also there's a cities table... What's the best way to sync them?

I have to sync cities, cuisine_tags and availability_restrictions first, then when creating restaurants i'll match them? Is this the right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this....

You should have all of the "Restaurant" properties (i.e. restirctions, cuisine-tags) within the restaurant object.

Here's an example:

```
{
    "Restaurants" : [
        { 
            "id" : "3",
            "name" : "...",
            "slug" : "...",
            "phone" : "2161234567",
            "address" : "...",
            "city_id" : "34",
            "county_id" : "426",
            "discount_type_id" : null,
            "discount" : "",
            "people_limit" : "2",
            "reservations_required" : false,
            "lat" : "41.015608",
            "lon" : "28.934834",
            "about" : "...",
            "logo" : "...",
            "logo_dir" : "3",
            "photo_1" : "...",
            "photo_2" : null,
            "photo_3" : null,
            "photo_dir" : "3",
            "created" : "2012-11-30 16:30:21",
            "modified" : "2012-11-30 20:43:50",
            "deleted" : true,
            "AvailabilityRestrictions" : [
                {
                    "id" : "1",
                    "title" : "..."
                },
                {
                    "id" : "2",
                    "title" : "..."
                }
            ],
            "CuisineTags" : [
                {
                    "id" : "3",
                    "name" : "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also get rid of the "Restaurant" object, it's unneeded. If I have an array called Restaurants. I want to only put/get Restaurants in/from it.

I think you had more to your question but I had trouble understanding what you need. Are you talking about how to set up relationships between them in Core Data?

If you are looking to set relationships between cruisine tags and cities or whatever I think this is the best way to go because you can loop throught the JSON response and if one of the attributes is a list you can determine the list and fetch the correct managed object and create the relationship.

Just to be clear, you should keep these cities, predefined cruise-tags in a different request though. You want to keep your API simple and flexible.

Comment: Yes now i'm trying to reformat JSON like this. Will CoreData auto match fields with this formatting?

And what about "cities" table? How can i match city_id?

Comment: First read this: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/ and FULLY understand it. You don't want a change in your API to mess up the app.

Comment: If you're new to Core Data you should also check out `Magical Record` and read this article to understand how to properly thread it http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

Comment: Thanks. One more question is; when creating new coredata object (i have Cities entity synced) how can i match city with Cities managedobject?

Comment: I would add a unique id that you can use to fetch the City managed object and set the `restaurant.city` relationship. With Magical Record fetching is as easy as: `[City findFirstByAttribute:@"uid" withValue:idOfCity];`

Comment: Also, for the sake of clarity you shouldn't have an entity named `Cities` instead it should be `City` and say an restaurant is in many cities it should have a to-many relationship with the name `cities` i.e. `someRestaurant.cities` . It will make things much clearer for you and anyone else who touches this code.